# How to add point to the beginning of series, Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need to dramatically add point

1. to the end and
2. to the beginning, .

but  keeping the data's length the same

I use

```
 chart.series[i].addPoint(1 * 5, false, true);
```

to achieve #1

But I can't find an API to add point to the beginning that shift off the last point.

```
   $("#prev").click(function(){
        chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas', 'Lemon']);

        for (var i = 0; i < chart.series.length; i++)
        {
            chart.series[i].data[4].remove(false);
            //TODO add point to the head
        }
       chart.redraw();
    });
```

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bvuWR/187/

Comment: In case when you would like to keep the same amount of points, maybe better is cal [point.update()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Point.update) on first and last point, applaying new value?

Comment: Or, you could also re-build the data array and use setData, if the x values aren't going to be the same: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.setData

Comment: @SebastianBochan , actually what i need is to move the series from right to left(remove last point and insert a point to the head so that the other points move forward). So if I use update() method, i have to update all the point?

Comment: @jlbriggs , can I have a fiddle?

Comment: So after movement, you add a new poitn and update first? Its a little bit unclear what you need to update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by:

1. update categories so that there is a new category at the head:
2. remove last point by data[i].remove(false)
3. add point to the head by: series[i].addPoint({x:headIndex,y:value},false,false)
4. chart.redraw()

Here is the demo:http://jsfiddle.net/wesu4daz/3/

And the Code Snippets:

```
//add point to last
$('#add').off('click').on('click',function(){
    var next = parseInt($(this).attr('end'),10)+1;
    var prev =  parseInt($('#prev').attr('start'),10)+1;

    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();

    //IMPORTANT to update categories before add point to the head
    var newCategories = $.merge([],chart.xAxis[0].categories);
    newCategories.push('new'+(newCategories.length))
    chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(newCategories);

    chart.series[0].addPoint({x:next,y:next},false,true);//add to last
    chart.redraw();

    $(this).attr('end',next);
    $('#prev').attr('start',prev);

});

//remove last point and add point to head
$('#prev').off('click').on('click',function(){
    var next = parseInt($('#add').attr('end'),10)-1;
    var prev =  parseInt($('#prev').attr('start'),10)-1;
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    console.log(chart.xAxis[0]);
    chart.series[0].data[3].remove(false);
    chart.series[0].addPoint({x:prev,y:prev},false,false);
    chart.redraw();

    $('#add').attr('end',next);
    $('#prev').attr('start',prev);
});
```